# AutoFit not working (Using the width of the header for AutoFit)

Tags: excel, vba

I've got the following code

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

But my data looks like this when I do that

[image]

It looks like it is trying to autofit with the width of the header, but I want to autofit with the width of what is on row 2 (In reality it will contain a lot more of data, so I will need it to AutoFit with the longest text on a cell in those columns)

Comment: Do those cells have Wrap Text applied?

Comment: @BigBen They don't

Comment: @BigBen actually, they do, I don't know why because I just copied and pasted the data into a brand new sheet, never applied a Wrap Text.

Comment: Copy/paste values instead. But here just remove the Wrap Text to autofit as you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns had an WrapText applied. This is why the AutoFit was not working.